# How to use PHP to change entered text

Tags: php, regex, sed

Ok so I have a common html form on a website in which users can write in and submit content.

I am wanting to write a piece of PHP that gets the whole text and converts some specific values.

For example, the text:

> > > Etiam non purus in dolor placerat sollicitudin. In dignissim elit ut libero sodales a sodales nunc blandit. Suspendi sse vitae odio mauris, eu pulvinar augue. In sit amet libero vel tellus posuere volutpat. twitter::Lipsum facebook::Lipsum Nulla sed purus vel orci ultrices tincidunt. Maecenas non sem eget risus volutpat placerat.

Notice the
facebook::Lipsum
twitter::Lipsum

I would like the php to look through that text and know that facebook::Lipsum should be automatically changed to http://www.facebook.com/Lipsum and the twitter one http://www.twitter.com/Lipsum

Could anyone advise on how to do this (with preg_match or str_replace)? I'm not sure have searched for a while and haven't found anything specific.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you want this on client side, you'll have to use javascript.

Comment: Use my code instad of Javascript, because Js can be turned of in some browsers, for security or other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generically replace any text containing the :: marker like so:

```
$text = "Etiam non purus in dolor placerat sollicitudin. In dignissim elit ut libero sodales a sodales nunc blandit. Suspendi sse vitae odio mauris, eu pulvinar augue. In sit amet libero vel tellus posuere volutpat. twitter::Lipsum facebook::Lipsum Nulla sed purus vel orci ultrices tincidunt. Maecenas non sem eget risus volutpat placerat.";

preg_replace("[(\w+)::]", "http://www.$1.com/", $text);
```

which says grab any text chunk containing :: and replace with `http://www.{string}.com/`

`[(\w+)::]` means match any word characters and end on :: - braces mean whole containing this, so just [::] would only replace the :: while [(\w+) starts with any word until it meets ::] and assigns that value within the () to the variable $1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: this seems better than my answer. but what does [(\w+)::] mean?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this will only match twitter and facebook

```
preg_replace("/(facebook|twitter)::([\w]+)/", '<a href="http://www.$1.com/$2" target="_blank">http://www.$1.com/$2</a>', $yourText);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hs3xgw

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `preg_*` functions:

```
$arr = array(
    'twitter' => 'www.twitter.com',
    'facebook' => 'www.facebook.com'
    // use lowercase keys here
    // or uncomment the next line
);
//$arr = array_change_key_case($arr,CASE_LOWER);

function replaceLinks($m) {
    global $arr;
    // make this array accessible
    $key = $m[1];   // this is the array key
    $page = $m[2];  // this is the part after ::
    $addr = 'http://'.$arr[strtolower($key)].'/'.$page;
    // get the value (address) from the array
    return "<a href=\"$addr\" target=\"_blank\">$addr</a>";
    // and return it as an anchor element
}

$newStr = preg_replace_callback(
    '~\b('.implode('|',array_keys($arr)).')::(\S*)~i',
    // this will basically compile into the following pattern:
    // ~\b(twitter|facebook)::(\S+)~i
    // where \b signifies beginning of word
    // and \S* signifies 0 or more non empty chars
    // so don't forget to urlencode or rawurlencode
    // the part after :: just in case
    'replaceLinks', // execute this function
    $str
);

echo "<p>$newStr</p>";
```